# How to format numbers to 3 decimal place in datagridview using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, format

I have a vb.net windows forms application that is using a datagridview. I'm hoping to find a simple way to format certain datagridview cells numbers upto 3 decimal places. This is what I have done so far, but it doesn't seem to format everything correctly.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.###"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to format everything correctly."?  What doesn't it format correctly?

Comment: If I use this to format the entire datagridview as a whole it seems to work fine. However one of my column indices seems to be problematic and it won't format correctly. Meaning that it still has decimals beyond the thousandths place.

Comment: The code is correct.  A simple mistake would be to put a string in the cell instead of a value of type Double or Decimal.

Comment: I had similar issue and the root cause was a forgotten routine which changed the format after I had set it.  So if this does not work, check your code for further calls that change the format.  It will work on populated datagridviews.

Answer (score 21):

Do you try with this one?

```
DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
```

Also this one may helpful:

- [Format Datagridview columns to numeric](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/95e7e7ef-2e71-412f-abe5-ffbee2c12c18/how-to-format-datagridview-columns-to-numeric-columndefaultcellstyleformat-does-not-work?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Comment: Format strings are described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(2), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

or

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(2), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.Add("TEST", "TEST")
    DataGridView1.Columns("TEST").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
    DataGridView1.Columns("TEST").ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue too. but my code is:

```
for R = 0 to DataGridView1.rows.count-1
DataGridView1.rows(r).cells(3).value=math.round(DataGridView1.rows(r).cells(3).value,2)
Next
```

`R` is for the Currentrow of DataGridView1  3 is your Column
i used to round of the datagridview cells in "2" decimal places and i fixed the problem :)

hope it can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#.###"
```

by:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
```

where `"N3"` means numeric data with three decimals. If all columns are to be `"N3"`, you can do it at once with:

```
DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
```

you can also apply a general cell alignment, to all cells in the data grid, for instance:

```
DataGridView1.DefaulCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
```

Finally, you can also define general (all columns) numeric format at DataGridView properties window, with Format option under DataGridViewCellStyle box.

And as you can see, there is no need for loops here while the style definitions are not specific.