# Limit datagridview to numeric only vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview on a windows form in vb.net. In one or more columns I want the text to be limited to numbers, including negative signs and one decimal point. I have the column property "format" set to 3 digit numbers, but I can still enter any text I want. So what is the trick to get VB to use the property?

I used this with no change in the behavior.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=vs.110).aspx

I also tried this with no change in the behavior.

```
DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3"
```

from here:
[How to format numbers to 3 decimal place in datagridview using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053128/how-to-format-numbers-to-3-decimal-place-in-datagridview-using-vb-net)

Comment: So do you want characters to be restricted in these columns while typing, or do you want validation to check to see if the edited cells are valid?

Comment: The top two answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12645458/832052) should help.

Comment: The underlying datatype of the columns datasource will do that for you

Comment: this is an unbound datagridview in vb.net
The link is for C++ I think.
I don't care the method. Why is there a property for this when VB ignores the property?
How can I populate the cells with numbers that are not considered strings when the data source is unbound? I'm loading the data from a textfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're building off of what you have, and you just want to change it to 3 decimal places, try the following:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    If Not IsNumeric(DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex).Value) Then
        DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex).Value = ""
    Else
        DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex).Value = Decimal.Parse(DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex).Value).ToString("N3")
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note that this answer will round the third decimal place if a fourth exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it works. But how can I limit the number to 3 decimal places?

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        If Not IsNumeric(DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex).Value) Then
            DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex).Value = ""
        End If
End Sub
```